# chrome-driver start-maximized not working in MAC OS

Tags: google-chrome, automation, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

In windows OS, the browsers launched perfectly with the below configuration. But in MAC chrome browser is not fully maximized.

*My Config File:*

```
config.framework = 'jasmine2';
config.allScriptsTimeout = timeout;
config.getPageTimeout = timeout;
config.jasmineNodeOpts.isVerbose = true;
config.jasmineNodeOpts.defaultTimeoutInterval = timeout;
config.specs = [
    'qa/**/*Spec.js'
];

config.multiCapabilities = [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 17,
    'chromeOptions': {
        'args': ['start-maximized']
    }
}];
```

Environment Details:

- Chome Browser  57.0.2987.110
- ChromeDriver 2.28.455520
- Protractor Version 5.1.1
- npm Version 3.10.10
- Node Version v6.10.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could also add start-fullscreen argument in your chrome options instead of using  `browser.driver.manage().window().maximize()`.
I was having the same issue and this resolved it on Mac.

```
   chromeOptions: {
    args: [
        '--start-fullscreen'
    ]
  }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the below piece of code in `onPrepare()` to maximize the browser instead of depending on the chrome args and see if that works.

```
 onPrepare: function() {
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
       }
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, We are currently doing that using onPrepare to maximize the browser window. But wanna know why it is not working in MAC.

Comment: oh ok ! Got it .. added the tags related to chromeDriver as this might be a compatibility issue from the chromium team. Also would suggest raising a ticket with chromium team for better help.